# Find width of attributed text in a UILabel when the text has multiple lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have multiline attributed text in a UILabel that I would like to find the width of. The purpose of this is to resize the font size for different devices. To do this I check whether the text with line breaks will fit a given space. I have tried `text.size.width`, however this will give the width as if the text is taking up one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

Here we get the size the entire `NSAttributedString`

```
 CGRect paragraphRect =
      [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300.f, CGFLOAT_MAX)
      options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
      context:nil];
```

You can then use it to find the width of the NSAttributedString
Hope this helps you out.